# Setup SSH Tunnel for KILN in PuTTY

Tags: kiln, baker

**Situation:**

The baker is running on a server with terminal only. I manage the server through a SSH authenticated PuTTY connection. I compiled and run KILN with:

```
./backend -network mainnet
```

and the application is running with the following output:

[image]

**Desired Result:**

I want to manage the KILN monitor on my local Firefox browser:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

**Questions:**

How do I have to configure PuTTY for this purpose? Is the following config tab the right one?

[image: PuTTY SSh Tunnel Configuration]

Comment: Nor sure if I understand your question correctly, but wouldn't it be easier and more efficient to just use the IP-address of your server that runs Kiln in the browser of your local machine, for instance: 10.0.220.20:8000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

My initial problem was that I used the external IP in the tunnel configuration. The following solves the problem [Reference to documentation on PuTTY tunnels](https://serverfault.com/questions/272754/what-is-the-difference-between-local-remote-dynamic-ssh-tunneling):

1) Set "Source Port" for the port on your local machine: 8000.

2) Set "Destination" to your *internal* IP address on the remote machine including port 8000 as highlighted in the screenshot and press "add".

3) Make sure to save the configuration afterwards.

[image: Screenshot of configuration. Remark: This is the internal IP of my server where you have to enter the one of yours]