# Binding the node to any address, not just localhost

Tags: rpc, node

Anyone know how to run node to bind to all address? I seem not to be able to rpc connect remotely, it binds to 127.0.0.1 and nothing else.
I set up in the config file listen address to 0.0.0.0:8732, also tried *:8732 and i cannot connect with rpc from another host. Is this by design, or am i missing something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using a configuration file, there are two different ports : the `"listen-addr"` option can be used both in the `"p2p"` section and in the `"rpc"` section. You can use `"0.0.0.0:8732"` for example to listen on port 8732 on all addresses.

You can also use the command line:

```
tezos-node run --rpc-addr 0.0.0.0:8732
```

Comment: Tried it in rpc section of the config file, it did not work, but i start the node with this command: tezos-node run, i assume it will use the parameter from the config file.

Comment: It needs to be run on the command line, the config file does not work to start it and bind on all address

Comment: I don't see any reason why it wouldn't use the configuration file option. We use that here. Unless you overwrite the option with an argument in a starting script.

Comment: How can this be done running docker containers? Tried `./mainnet.sh start --rpc-addr 0.0.0.0:8732` but I'm getting `tezos-node: option --rpc-addr cannot be repeated`

Answer (score 2):

To listen on all interfaces, leave the IP address out completely.

```
tezos-node run --rpc-addr :8732
```

Comment: I will try it, and report back

Comment: @Zx1984 Did you get a chance to try?

Comment: Yes i did, sorry for the delay, it works, it seems the configuration file ws being overidden when specified from the command line, which should have been obvious to be honest. It's one of those Doh! moments

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding the problem, but wouldn't it be a solution to build up a secure SSH connection to the server an tunnel the address 127.0.0.1:8732 of the remote machine to the local host who wants to connect?

I did it [this way here](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/157/setup-ssh-tunnel-for-kiln-in-putty/178#178) in order to look at the KILN config from my local Firefox.