# Kiln remote Node Connection

Tags: baking, kiln

I've 2 machines running. Machine 1 (Ubuntu 18.04) runs the node and Machine 2 (Virtual Box NixOS) runs Kiln 0.4.0.

I've started my Node on Machine 1 (like described [here](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/238/binding-the-node-to-any-address-not-just-localhost?answertab=active#tab-top)) with:

```
tezos-node run --rpc-addr 0.0.0.0:8732
```

What do I have to enter in Kiln (Machine 2) to add the Node from Machine 1? The local IP from Machine 1 doesn't work.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by `The local IP from Machine 1 doesn't work.`?

Comment: The 2 Machines are on the same network. So i've tried to enter  192.168.xxx.xxx:8732 (that's the IP of the Machine where the node runs) in Kiln.
Kiln says: "Unable to connect".

Comment: Do you have some firewall rules getting in the way?

Comment: My node (Machine 1) connects via VPN to the I-net. But that shouldn't influence my local connectivity? No firewall rules. Is the described way correct?

Comment: Is it even possible, to connect to something outside the Virtual Box?

Answer (score 1):

I got some protocol errors when I tried adding just `<ip>:<port>` so I had to use `http://<ip>:<port>`

Don't know if that helps, but worked for me. ‍♂️

Comment: Yeah, "http://" is now mandatory with kiln 0.4.0. So i've tried that already. :(

Comment: @Blindripper can you `telnet <macine-1-ip> 8732` from machine 2? If no then you have a network issue not related to the node or kiln.

Also try `telnet <machine-1-ip> 8732` from machine 1 to verify you are binding to the interface.

Comment: If its not binding, how do you make sure it binds on machine 1 so machine 2 can connect?